# Javascript related Question (operators and precedence)

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I am learning operators and precedence and I am trying to make a form that calculates a batter's slugging percentage. In the text fields the users have to input the name of the batter the amount of singles, doubles, triples, and homers the player has hit and then they click calculate and it shows their slugging percentage. The following equations will be used to figure this out.  Slugging Percentage  = Total Bases ÷ At Bats, and  • Total Bases = Singles + (2 x Doubles) + (3 x Triples) + (4 x Home Runs). My question is in what order would I write the equation for these.
The code below is still in the works and I still need to finish a couple of variables but this is the code I have for this project and I was wondering if someone could explain the order i should write the equations in.

```
<html !doctype>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Lab7 Baseball Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calculation() {

            var batterName = parseFloat(document.getElementById('battername').value);
            var ofBat = parseFloat(document.getElementById)('ofbat').value);
            var ofSingles = parseFloat(document.getElementById)('ofsingles').value);
            var ofDoubles = parseFloat(document.getElementById)('ofdoubles').value);
            var ofTriples = parseFloat(document.getElementById)('oftriples').value);
            var ofHome = parseFloat(document.getElementById)('ofhome').value);
            var totalBases =






        }

    </script>


</head>

<body>
    <h1>Slugging Percentage Calculator</h1>
    <form>
        Batter's Name: <input type="text" id="battername" /><br />
        Enter number of At Bats: <input type="text" id="ofbat" /><br />
        Enter number of Singles: <input type="text" id="ofsingles" /><br />
        Enter number of Doubles: <input type="text" id="ofdoubles" /><br />
        Enter number of Triples: <input type="text" id="oftriples" /><br />
        Enter number of Home Runs:<input type="text" id="ofhome" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Whats his slugging percentage?" onclick="calculation()">






</form>
```

Comment: You already have the order in your pseudo code. Write it out like that using your variables. It will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Randy is right. Order of operations basically works like math. It'll evaluate the parentheses and then sum everything. You could leave out the parentheses even, but they're nice for readability.